# Работа с COM портом C++

Tags: c++, windows, port

Нужно написать программу для обмена данными с устройством по виртуальному COM порту. Прога утыкается в ReadFile и дальше не едет. Пробовал разные примеры что нашел в сети - результат тот же.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



int main()
{
    DCB dcb;

    HANDLE port = CreateFile("COM9",
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        0,
        NULL);

    BuildCommDCB("baud=9600 parity=N data=8 stop=1", &dcb);

    char buf_out[1024] = "$016";
    char buf_in[1024];
    DWORD oSize = sizeof(buf_out);
    DWORD BytesWritten;
    DWORD iSize;


    while (1)
    {
        WriteFile(port, buf_out, oSize, &BytesWritten, NULL);
        ReadFile(port, &buf_in, sizeof(buf_in), &iSize, 0);
        cout << buf_in << endl;
    }

    CloseHandle(port);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё правильно, ReadFile это блокирующая операция. После её вызова она ожидает прихода данных. Так как ты данные не посылаешь, она их всё время ожидает.

Напиши отдельное маленькое приложение которое будет посылать данные на указанный порт.
Бонусом будет использование не winapi, а [boost.asio](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html).

Comment: Там где-то в параметрах можно указать таймаут, в течении которого ReadFile будет ждать ответа.